# raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)

Tags: django, smtp, sendmail

registration app .
I follow toturial on http://agiliq.com/books/djenofdjango/chapter5.html for setting up an
email verfication and it suggest following confgiuration for setting.py

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "user@example.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "secret"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

but i got error about SMTP supporting of TLS in some forum I read to comment the EMAIL_USE_TLS
then I got the aut method error and again from some forum I read to comment     EMAIL_HOST_USER = "user@example.com" and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "secret" but know I got the following error :

```
raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
Exception Type: SMTPSenderRefused at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: (502, '5.5.1 Unrecognized command. h47sm103656655eey.13 - gsmtp', u'webmaster@localhost')
```

I'm really confused about how to config setting.py for sending email .

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. but I stumbled on this https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and I followed. It tourned out the 2-Step-Verification  wasn't allowing my app to send any mail.

I just clicked on the link related to  [**2-Step-Verification**](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en&ctx=ch_DisplayUnlockCaptcha) and end up **Signing in using App Passwords**

by changing :

`EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "secret"`

to the generated 16-characters password :

`EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "newlygeneratedsecret"`

Hope I helped. I'm told  ( https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44768/limitations-on-sending-email-through-gmail-smtp/48393#48393 ) that if Gmail sees you sending a lot of e-mails, it may request you to manually sign in. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the below code. I have used the below code and got the solution for the above-mentioned issue. I am sending HTML body that's why I have used *MIMEText(variable, "html")* if you want to use text please use MIMEText(variable, "text").

```
    me = "your email"
    you = "email of person whom you want to send the mail"
    msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
    msg["Subject"] = "Subject String"
    msg["From"] = me
    msg["To"] = you
    # message to be sent
    #for HTML as a part of mail body
    html = '<html><body><p></a>Testing HTML/a></p></body></html>'
    part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")
    msg.attach(part2)
    s = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    s.starttls()
    s.login(me, "password of your mail")
    # sending the mail
    s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
    # terminating the session`enter code here`
    s.quit()
```